# passing the image to dompdf

Tags: pdf-generation, dompdf, html2canvas

I have the following code in my save.php:

```
<?php 
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$LgPath=$_POST['image'];
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.png");

$html = file_get_contents($LgPath);
//$html = readfile($LgPath); --only shows the image

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
?>
```

I take succesfully using HTML2CANVAS the print screen of some  element, and then i pass it to the save.php page using $POST. I want that using DOMPDF to put that image in the sample.pdf. Using this code I only have this text in the sample.pdf "‰PNG", and I have don't figure how to fix it. Using readfile i see the image, but that's it...  Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading your image into a variable and passing it to dompdf. As such dompdf is treating that text that makes up that image as HTML source. Since your image is readable from the PHP script at the location stored in `$LgPath` you should be able to do something like this:

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$LgPath=$_POST['image'];
$html = '<img src="' . $LgPath . '">';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
?>
```

Comment: in the meantime I've used other variant in which I write the image to server, and from there pass it to  the dompdf. But i prefer your variant. Thanks allot for your simple solution, which seem to avoid me... p.s. now i only need to figure out why when I try to print from the sample.pdf, the image is not in the top of the page but in the vertical-middle of the page :)

Comment: That's an odd problem. If the image appears correct on screen it could be your print settings. Check out how the PDF rendered is set to "fit" the page. If that's not it a new question may be in order.

Comment: yes, the image is fitting the page and is going down.. seem that if I use the same proportions of the image passed to the dimensions of the page manually, then the image take position on the top. I leave it like this, even if the dimensions are under the A4 specs, the differences of quality are not visible on the naked eye or when printing :). Thank you again for your answer.